# Changing labels in SciChart 3D Tooltip using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

Is there a way to change the "Text" property of the tooltip modifier, using C#?

I want to change these labels:

[image: Image from *https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/webframe.html#TooltipModifier3D.html*]

I'm using "*WaterfallRenderableSeries3D*".

My Code:

```
<s3D:SciChart3DSurface x:Name="SciChartView1" 
            Height="850" Width="1400" 
            Margin="50,100,50,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.RenderableSeries>
                <s3D:WaterfallRenderableSeries3D x:Name="WaterfallSeriesView1" Style="{StaticResource WaterfallSeriesStyle}"/>
            </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.RenderableSeries>

            <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>
                <s3D:NumericAxis3D/>
            </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>

            <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.YAxis>
                <s3D:NumericAxis3D/>
            </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.YAxis>

            <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.ZAxis>
                <s3D:NumericAxis3D/>
            </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.ZAxis>

            <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.ChartModifier>
                <s3D:ModifierGroup3D>
                    <s3D:TooltipModifier3D CrosshairMode="Lines" IsEnabled="True"
                               SourceMode="AllSeries" ShowTooltipOn="MouseOver">
                    </s3D:TooltipModifier3D>
                </s3D:ModifierGroup3D>
            </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.ChartModifier>
        </s3D:SciChart3DSurface>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the labels on the Tooltips in SciChart WPF 3D by applying a template in XAML.

Have a look at the [SciChart WPF 3D Chart Documentation on Tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/248362/303612).

> Styling the Tooltip Item Template
>
> The tooltip item template can be styled in exactly the same was as the RolloverModifier, via the TooltipModifier3D.TooltipTemplate attached property. This defines a DataTemplate for some UI which binds to an instance of SeriesInfo. For a full description of the SeriesInfo types please see  RolloverModifier
>
> ```
> <!-- where xmlns:s3D="http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/scichart3D" -->
> <s3D:SciChart3DSurface>
>    <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.Resources>
>
>         <s3D:Vector3ComponentConverter x:Key="Vector3ComponentConverter" />
>
>         <DataTemplate x:Key="XyzSeriesTooltipTemplate" DataType="cd:BaseXyzSeriesInfo3D">
>             <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
>                 <TextBlock>
>                     <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding SeriesName, FallbackValue='Xyz 3D Point', TargetNullValue='Xyz 3D Point'}" />
>                 </TextBlock>
>                 <Border
>                     Height="1"
>                     Margin="3"
>                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
>                     Background="DimGray"
>                     BorderThickness="0" />
>                 <TextBlock>
>                     <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="X: " />
>                     <Run Text="{Binding HitVertex, Converter={StaticResource Vector3ComponentConverter}, ConverterParameter='X'}" />
>                 </TextBlock>
>                 <TextBlock>
>                     <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Y: " />
>                     <Run Text="{Binding HitVertex, Converter={StaticResource Vector3ComponentConverter}, ConverterParameter='Y'}" />
>                 </TextBlock>
>                 <TextBlock>
>                     <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Z: " />
>                     <Run Text="{Binding HitVertex, Converter={StaticResource Vector3ComponentConverter}, ConverterParameter='Z'}" />
>                 </TextBlock>
>             </StackPanel>
>         </DataTemplate>
>    </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.Resources>
>
>    <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.RenderableSeries>
>       <s3D:XyScatterRenderableSeries3D s3D:TooltipModifier3D.IncludeSeries="False"
>                                        s3D:TooltipModifier3D.TooltipTemplate="{StaticResource XyzTooltipTemplate}"//>
>    </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.RenderableSeries>
> </s3D:SciChartSurface>
> ```

If you wanted to apply these changes in c# code you can also consider applying a template using the [following technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/248362/303612) or [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45920246/303612).

Comment: I really appreciate all your help Dr. ABT. Thanks!